# Creating a SET of strings in Redis but returning integers

Tags: python, django, redis

Noticing that when I try to add a list of strings to my redis_instance as members of a SET when I try to retrieve the elements in this SET  I only see integers. From how I read the documentation if I were to for example have a set containing:

```
'Fred', 'Emmanuel', 'Marcus Aurelius'
```

If I were to return the entire SET, assuming the key for the set is 'newSet' by running this command:

```
SMEMBERS pairs
```

I should see a list of all members of said state, instead this is the response I get:

```
 1) "32"
 2) "39"
 3) "44"
 4) "65"
 5) "69"
 6) "70"
 7) "77"
 8) "91"
 9) "93"
10) "97"
11) "99"
12) "100"
13) "101"
14) "105"
15) "108"
16) "109"
17) "110"
18) "114"
19) "115"
20) "117"
```

This is the code I am using to create and append to said set:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def manage_items(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = []
        count = 0
        for elem in redis_instance.smembers("pairs"):
            items.append(elem.decode("utf-8"))
            count += 1
        response = {
            'count': count,
            'msg': f"Found {count} items.",
            'items': items
        }
        return Response(response, status=200)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        new_users = request.body
        for i in range(0, len(new_users)):
            redis_instance.sadd('pairs', bytes(str(new_users[i]), "utf-8"))
        response = {
            'msg': f'set contains: {new_users}'
        }
        return Response(response, 201)
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with python, but are you sure you did the right job with `request.body`? Since I know you had to convert `request.body` to `str` and then to an array and then perform the iteration on that. But what you did is just storing `request.body`, a byte array, in a variable and perform iteration on that array and convert each item to a string. So you are storing each item of the `request.body` byte array to Redis.

**UPDATE:**

These byte arrays are different. `request.body` represents the body of the HTTP request, which web frameworks usually encode as a byte array. The HTTP request body is literally a String, not just of the type of `str` in python. In your case request body is a string likes `['Fred', 'Emmanuel', 'Marcus Aurelius']` this string will be encoded as a byte array in `request.body` you need to decode it as a python `str` and then an array. For more clarification,blow example:

```
#The array that the client sends to the server would be something like this:
str_1 = "['Fred', 'Emmanuel', 'Marcus Aurelius']"
#The array, which actually is a string, reaches the server as a byte array. The whole string is converted to a byte array, not each element separately. Something like we do in python with blow code. str_1_encoded is actually the request.body
str_1_encoded = str_1.encode(encoding = 'UTF-8')
#If you put a for on this array
for bytes in str_1_encoded:
    print(bytes, end = ' ')
#You will get a result like this
>>> 91 39 70 114 101 100 39 44 32 39 69 109 109 97 110 117 101 108 39 44 32 39 77 97 114 99 117 115 32 65 117 114 101 108 105 117 115 39 93
# Which is completely different from what you've sent.
# But you should do like this
text = str(request.body, "utf-8")
text = text[1:-1]
text = text.split(',')
for el in text:
    print(el, end = ' ')
>>> 'Fred'  'Emmanuel'  'Marcus Aurelius'
```

Comment: Wait, from my understanding I'm getting a byte (I guess I don't need to convert this already byte element to a byte), converting that into a string and then storing the string in Redis? Should I not be getting a string then If I request data from Redis?

Comment: @Emm My comment became so long that I updated my answer.